# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "10 puntos"?

Tags: modismos, argentina

En el modismo mexicano se dice "5 estrellas", pero en argentino es "10 puntos":

> A: ¡Hola, che! ¿Cómo estás?
>
> B:  ¡Joya, che, re bien! ¿Y vos?
>
> A: ¡10 puntos, chamigo, ¡gracias totales!

Me gustaría saber de dónde viene la expresión "10 puntos".

Comment: A veces también se oye la expresión "de tres puntos" que alude a la canasta de máximo valor en el baloncesto. Viene a ser un símil con intentar algo difícil (lanzamiento de la pelota desde fuera del área) y obtener un resultado extraordinario.

Comment: como mexicano nunca había oido ese modismo, ¿en que parte del país lo escuchaste?

Comment: @motilio En Argentina

Comment: Para mi eso viene de las encuestas cuando te preguntan en una escala del 1 al 10 siendo el 10 máximo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 puntos es la calificación máxima en las escuelas. 
Por lo tanto "10 puntos" significa excelente.

En Venezuela serían 20 puntos.

Comment: Gracias, chamo!

Comment: En Chile: ¡un siete!

Comment: Caleta grax, tío

Comment: Que interesante. Así que ¿En Venezuela en exámenes la puntuación se da entre 0 y 20?

Comment: @alphamikevictor, no: curiosamente la puntuación más baja en Venezuela es 1 punto, la cual se lee y escribe "cero uno" (01). De hecho la expresión "cero uno" a veces se utiliza de manera análoga con el sentido de "eso fue una falla total".